# Create a Group of Objects That Hide or Unhide as One

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Is it possible to create something like a "visibility group" to toggle hiddenness on and off for many many many objects at once? Layers are great and all, but....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select a number of objects, and key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to add them to a new group. Then, whenever you want to hide them, key <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to open the *Select Grouped* menu and select *Group*.

Key <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all hidden objects.

[image]

Additionally, you can clear the group from any or all of the objects by selecting 1 or more and keying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>. You can also add more objects to the group. Do this by selecting the objects that you want to add, selecting an object that is part of the group, and keying <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

[image]

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: I use this often as replacement for layers in my scenes. Additionally you can quickly toggle visibility for entire groups in one click from an *Outliner* set to *Groups* option

Comment: Eh.... So OK: In 3 years I've found one thing Maya does better....  but I can live with this!

Comment: @rcgauer Well, if you've only found 1 thing Maya does better in 3 years, Blender is doing pretty good :) Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Or you can send the group to a hidden layer, add an instance to it (Add > Group). The instance behaves like a single object so no need to select all each time.

Comment: @qwazix Read the question. He doesn't like layers.

Comment: @Shady Puck -- Agreed~!

Comment: It's not the classic usecase of layers. In fact you could even link a group instance from another blend IIRC or maybe even scene. Layers are usually not optimal for group hiding as you only have so many. With this approach you only waste one layer and can show/hide as many groups you want with a single keystroke. I still believe it has some merit, though not enough to post it as an answer, thus the comment.